# Replacing backslashes with two backslashes using regex

Tags: regex, perl

How do I replace single backslashes in a string with double backslashes?

I've tried things such as

```
s/\\(?!\\)/\\\\/g
s/\\/\\\\/g
s/[^//]/\\\\/g
```

But they all produce multiple backslashes after each other.

So I want:

```
\test
```

to be replaced with

```
\\test
```

Edit: Sorry I should also mention that the regex is in a loop so I need a regex that only matches the string if there is ONLY ONE backslash. Once there is more than one backslash then the regex should reject the string. Apologies

Comment: Do you want double-blackslashes to become quadruple or not?

Comment: what about an even number of backslashes?

Comment: `$subject =~ s/\\(.*?)$/\\\\$1/g;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most helpful thing to note is to use a different delimiter for the regex, so things don't get jumbled by all the leaning towers:

```
my $str = '\test';

$str =~ s{\\}{\\\\}g;

print $str;
```

Outputs:

```
\\test
```

**Update**

Per your revised specification, if you only want to escape a single backslash, and ignore all others, then just use a negative lookahead and lookbehind assertion:

```
my $str = <<'END_STR';
\one \\two \\\three
END_STR

print $str;

$str =~ s{(?<!\\)\\(?!\\)}{\\\\}g;

print $str;
```

Outputs:

```
\one \\two \\\three
\\one \\two \\\three
```

Comment: Your regex is technically right but I've added more to my question, apologies.

Comment: @ashxu I've updated my answer per your revised spec.  Perhaps it's what you're wanting.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '\replace' | perl -pe 's/\\/\\\\/g'
\\replace
```

OR with sed

```
# echo '\replace' | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g'
\\replace
```